# For an R package, how to efficiently move a package from Depends to Imports

Tags: r, dependencies, r-package

Say I have a package that has 5 packages in `Depends` of the DESCRIPTION file and I have just realised it is not a good practice to have this many packages in `Depends` due to inevitable import clashes that are starting to pop up as the number of function imports are increasing. I'd like to move, say only package `pkg` to `Imports` but I have no clue which functions of `pkg` are being used in my package. Ideally, I should have unit tests with full coverage of the package source code and by simply removing `pkg` from the dependencies, I will identify the `pkg`-specific imports from the test errors of `could not find function "foo"`. But unfortunately, I do not have that breadth of test coverage. I was wondering if there is a more efficient way than going through all the package code to identify these imports.

Comment: @Al_J_Abadi if an answer solves your problem you should accept it.  See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is very straightforward.  Change

```
Depends: pkgA, pkgB, pgC
```

to

```
Imports: pkgA, pkgB, pgC
```

*and also add this to the `NAMESPACE` file*:

```
import("pkgA")
import("pkgB")
import("pkgC")
```

which will *globally* import all exported symbols so you can continue as before.

You can also selectively import via

```
importFrom("pkgA", "func1", "func2", "func3")
```

and if you run `R CMD check` it will actually (very helpfully) tell you which functions need this.  The second method is somewhat more precise but a little more work to set up.

And I don't think we have a tool to remove 'spurious imports'. Finding which imports may be unused may be something you have to check manually (but trying to remove one and seeing if it still builds + checks fine).

Comment: Thanks, @dirk-eddelbuettel. The `import('pkg')` method would still throw the clash warning and running `R CMD check` should do the trick.